# wine32 is missing issue in ubunt 20.04, [[as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32" wine-5.0 ]]

Tags: ubuntu, wine

enter code hereHow can i fixed the below wine32 missing issue in ubuntu 20.04 , i spent lot of time but did not get any luck.

## i installed wine-stable successfully,  but when i tried to checking the wine version i am getting this message and wine also not working... thanks advance for help.

Error:
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it. as root,

## > please execute "apt-get install wine32"

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu i also tried this instructions but not working.. same issue.

**Here is the details:

```
$ wine --version

> it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it. as root,
> please execute "apt-get install wine32"

**
wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
$ sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
$ sudo apt install libwine:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Same shit, this chain goes down to:
```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.1) but 245.4-4ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 libpulse0 : Breaks: libpulse0:i386 (!= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libpulse0:i386 : Breaks: libpulse0 (!= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2 is installed
```
I've already asked this on winehq forum.

Comment: yes, broomrider!!! seems this unmet dependencies goes down infinitive way... 
Please can you add your "winehq forum" here?

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title, instead accept the answer you found the most useful, which you've already done :)

Comment: Here is winehq link, but nothing special... only my posts there :)
https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=128186

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I've finally installed wine32 and all it dependencies on 20.04. The problem was here:
[image]

"Important" and "Recommendned" updates was disabled. They activates extra ubuntu repos, where newer version of `i386`-family presents. But, after installing, upgrading and rebooting I come to another irrelevant issue with initramfs, but this is different story.

Comment: My god, this fixed the problem, thank you !

Comment: OMG! it worked, too! I've been looking for weeks for a solution

Comment: Anyone knows how to enable this option from CLI (directly in files)? Because I don't have those checkboxes in this tab... (using Cinnamon)

Comment: You can checkout `/etc/apt/sources.list`. My current active repos are:
```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse main restricted universe
```

Comment: This is my `sources.list` → https://pastebin.com/1sxKvEY5 and I believe I have all branches as you mentioned, the only difference is I have `groovy`. I still can't install `wine32` without going through dependency hell..

Comment: I think the focal-groovy diff is the key.

Comment: How do you get to the above screen?

Comment: @Dirigo
For kde: alt-f2 → software settings → software sources